# how to create a context in function based component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

here is the context that i'm trying to create

```
import React,{Component, useState } from "react";

export const DojoContext = React.createContext() 
 const ThemeContextProvider = (props)=> {
    
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState({
      isLightTheme: true,
      light: { syntax: "#555", ui: "#ddd", bg: "#eee" },
      dark: { syntax: "#ddd", ui: "#333", bg: "#555" },
    });
  
    return (
      <div>
        <DojoContext.Provider value={{ ...theme }}>
            {props.children}
        </DojoContext.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default   ThemeContextProvider;
```

and here's the App component that wraps all other components as a childs

```
import React from "react";
import Dojo from "./pages/dojo";
import ThemeContextProvider from "./pages/tryContext";

function App() {
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeContextProvider>
        <Dojo/>
      </ThemeContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
  
  }

export default App;
```

```
import React,{Component, useContext} from "react";
import DojoContext from "./tryContext";
const Dojo = () => {

    const context = useContext(DojoContext)
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>console.log(context)}> log context </button>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Dojo;
```

So i want to print at the console the value of the context when the button is clicked to make sure that i can access to it's value

Comment: it looks like the console log should work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're exporting your context as a named variable. And when importing it in the `Dojo` component you actually import the `ThemeContextProvider`

```js
import DojoContext from "./tryContext";
```

Try

```js
import { DojoContext } from "./tryContext";
```